# Error al hacer deploy

Tags: java-ee

el archivo xml es el siguiente;

[image: xml]

Estoy  creando un descriptor `glassfish` file pero al darle *deploy* me sale el siguiente error :

> Grave:   Exception while deploying the app [MyApp] : java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in parsing sun-ejb-jar.xml for archive [C:\Users\MIGUEL ANGEL\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyApp\build\classes]: null
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in parsing sun-ejb-jar.xml for archive [C:\Users\MIGUEL ANGEL\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyApp\build\classes]: null
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.EjbJarHandler$SunEjbJarXMLParser.(EjbJarHandler.java:345)
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.EjbJarHandler.getClassLoader(EjbJarHandler.java:139)
>       at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:248)
>       at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createDeploymentClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:229)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:365)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>       at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Esfuerzate un poco mas al realizar la pregunta: dice que tienes un error en la sintaxis xml del archivo sun-ejb-jar.xml, asi que muestranos ese archivo y tal ves podamos ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: gracias ya edite  con una foto del xml

Comment: aun no se soluciona lo que pasa es que creo que es algo relacionado ala version de netbeans que uso es la 8.0.2 me aparece un error cuando quiero crear un "GlassFish Descriptor File"

Answer (score 0):

Creo ver un *espacio en blanco* antes de la declaración de DOCTYPE; Elimínalo.

Si no es así o sigue ocurriendo el error, prueba a quitar la declaración de DOCTYPE. El resto del documento parece estar bien.